# How to resize a "div" based on mouse drag in EmberJs?

Tags: ember.js

I am building grid in which the header needs to be resizable.

Basically, User can click on the edges of the header column then drag it for resize.

Currently I have a component for each header column and I suppose it needs some event handling here but I cannot figure out which one.

Please suggest on what approach should be followed.

*Note: I am using Ember version 1.13. Also, cannot use ember-table.*

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day when i did a similar thing i used

https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

So i made a component

*resizeable-widget.js*

```
didInsertElement: function() {

        this._super(...arguments);

        // $('#rezisable-widget').draggable({ scroll: true, scrollSpeed: 20});
        $('#rezisable-widget').resizable({
            minHeight: 210,
            minWidth: 500
        });
},
```

*resizeable-widget.hbs*

```
<div id="rezisable-widget" class="ui-widget-content">

</div>
```